# How to send mail with attachment in JavaScript via Gmail API

Tags: javascript, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to send a mail with attachment via Gmail API.

I'm successfully sending my mail as specified below:

```
function sendmail(to, subject, message) {
    var email =
        "To: " + to + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
        "" +
        message + "\r\n\r\n";
    var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
        'userId': 'me',
        'resource': {
            'raw': window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(email))).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
        }
    });

    sendRequest.execute();
}
```

Now I want to send some file as attachment and tried it in following way:

```
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onChange="convertToBase64();"/>
<script>
    var file_ = '';

    function convertToBase64() {
        //Read File
        var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            file_ = reader.result.split('base64,')[1];
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function sendmail(to, subject, message, date) {
        console.log(date);

        if (typeof file_ !== "undefined" && file_ != '') {
            var email =
                "To: " + to + "\r\n" +
                "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n' +
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
                "" +
                message +
                "\r\n\r\n" +
                "--foo_bar_baz\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n" +
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf\r\n\r\n" +
                file_ + "\r\n\r\n";
            var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
                'userId': 'me',
                'resource': {
                    'raw': window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(email))).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
                }
            });

            sendRequest.execute();
        } else {
            alert('boo');
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I would receive the mail BUT I see no text and cannot open the file because of 'bad coding!'.

I did check the whole gmail documentation but without avail.

Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/195) and this might be the same issue as in [#172](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/172). It looks like the message and attachments need to be a single mime document. *"Looking at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending, and reading the Java, it does seem like it message body and attachement(s) have to go into a single mime document, and then that get uploaded."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

I read somewhere that encoding pdf's as base64 require you to set the content transfer encoding accordingly.